# removeAttr does not work with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to remove the checked attribute from a set of radio buttons. I am using angularjs but I have tried with jquery and it is the same. Here is my code with angularjs:

```
 var radioList = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".radioButtons"));
        for (var i = 0; i <= radioList.length; i++) {
            radioList[i].removeAttr('checked');
        }
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: radioList[i].removeAttr is not a function
```

what am I doing wrong??
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
 Angular version:   AngularJS v1.5.8

Comment: Have you tried `removeAttribute`? Edit: what version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: Try `radioList[i].checked = false;`

Comment: I have tried both and nothig: TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of undefined

Comment: Why can't you just use `var radioList = document.querySelectorAll(".radioButtons"));` ?

Comment: I tried but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem adding a value into my input.

```
<input type="radio" name="presetRadio" id="{{filterData.id}}"
       ng-model="currentRule.filters"
       value="{{filterData.id}}"          
       ng-checked="filterData.active" />
```

Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 0):

Your are performing 1 extra loop your loop condition should be `i<` instead of `i<=` should be like

```
for (var i = 0; i < radioList.length; i++) {
            radioList[i].checked=true;
        }
```

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/csm4305g/)

Comment: I would like to set all radio buttons to false. But there is one that is true. In this demo it works. Why does not it work in my proyect?

Comment: @ABT because you are excecuting 1  extra loop in for loop i change `i <=radioList.length` to `i < radioList.length`

Comment: can you create a fiddle with you data

Answer (score 0):

First things first, angularJS makes use of jQuery internally so you can feel free to work with element selectors as you would do in jQuery. After calling the angular.element function, either you're returned no, one or multiple results you'll be returned a results array. As this array is jQuery-aware, you can call a jQuery function on its reference which will be called for every entry in the returned results array. So simply you can do this instead;

```
angular.element('.radioButtons').removeAttr('checked');
```